# File upload acceptfiletypes option

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4, blueimp

I am using the [Blueimp Fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with ASP.net MVC application,
I need to build RegEx acceptfiletypes option at runtime to accept
mime types that catch all possible Office MIME file types like:

```
> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  this regex to test if your mimetype is a Microsoft application. It is based on [this document](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list) which list most mime-types :

`application\/.*?(?:msword|x-ms|vnd\.ms-|officedocument)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8G73l/1)

**Sample snippet**

```js
const officeRegex = /application\/.*?(?:msword|x-ms|vnd\.ms-|officedocument)/;

const mimeTypes = [
  "application/msword",
  "application/pdf",
  "image/png",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
];

mimeTypes.forEach(function(mimeType) {
  console.log(officeRegex.test(mimeType));
});
```